# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( /timeline/scripts/collections/events.js?bust=1365755363650:1
```

Here's **/timeline/scripts/collections/events.js**:

```
function () {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Event

    ,   parse: function(data) {
            var parsed = [];
            $(data).find('Event').each(function(index) {
                parsed.push({
                    title: $(this).find('title').text()
                ,   date: $(this).find('date').text()
                ,   content: $(this).find('content').text()
                });
            });
            return parsed;
        }

    ,   fetch: function(options) {
            options = options || {};
            options.dataType = "xml";
            Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }
    });
};
```

For some reason it is choking on `function () {` but I can't work out why. This is the entire document. Can anyone explain what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function *declaration*, not a function expression. Function declarations must have names.

```
function foo () {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
```

Comment: Thanks I am using require.js to load this and have seen other examples of people using anonymous functions like so... back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: Generally speaking, when using require JS, the file will consist of a call to the `define` method with a function expression passed as an argument. You wouldn't have the function just sitting in the file.

Comment: Interesting the tutorial I followed must of omitted it but it does indeed solve the issue. Thanks x 2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an anonymous function without calling it.

Comment: You cannot "declare" an anonymous function at all. It's a syntax error, even if it is immediately invoked. It has to be parsed as an expression, not a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

When one syntax checker doesn't give a useful error message, try another one.

I'm usually a fan of the Chrome developer tools, but in this case Chrome doesn't give a very good error message. So I tried pasting your code into Firefox, and it was *much* more helpful:

```
SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
    function () {
```

I also got that same error message by pasting your code into [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) which has live syntax checking while you edit. (Not surprising the message is the same since Komodo is based on Firefox.)

It pays to try different tools when one isn't helping.